# Echo foo based on if $bar is isset

Tags: php

Normally when I retrieve an array from the database, I check to see if a certain element exists or is set to a certain value and echo text out accordingly:

```
if (isset($bar)) // or is true 
{
  echo "something";
}
else  // elseif is set to false
{
  echo "not something";
}
```

But once you lots of variables, it can make your code quite an eyesore. I know you can easily create a function to do this, but does php provide an functionality built in to do this? What do fellow SOs do to get around this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I find the [ternary operator](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison) to be less of an eye-sore in these situations.

So

```
echo (isset($bar) ? 'something' : 'not something');
```

Answer (score 3):

Define your own function and use it. Something like this

```
function echo_if_isset($foo) {
    if (isset($foo))
       echo $foo;
}

echo_if_isset($bar);
```

Comment: This will produce a non-fatal error "Notice: Undefined variable: bar ..."

Comment: You can use pass by reference (&) to prevent PHP from checking the value before you do.
`function echo_if_set(&$foo) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is a bit more complex that what you present here but I'll give it a shot.

1st) I normally pull records out of the db using mysql_fetch_assoc()

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM something";
$qr = mysql_query( $q );

$qrow = mysql_fetch_assoc( $q );
```

2nd) Use a for loop

```
foreach( $qrow as $k => $v )
{
    if( strlen( $v ) )
    {
        echo "the value is: $v\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "the value is blank\n";
    }
}
```